# regex subtraction

Tags: c++, regex, bash, c++11, regex-negation

Is it possible to use regex character class subtraction in some way in GNU sed, GNU awk, GNU grep, or anywhere else from bash?

Is it supported in C++11?

Where this feature is supported? I was unable to find any references except this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx (at the bottom).

To be more specific: what's the best way to convert all the digits except 2 and 5 to asterisks, something like

`sed -re 's/[0-9-[25]]/*/g'`

Comment: What is the target language? C++? C#? Each language has different level of support for regex.

Comment: bash and c++11. «bash» means also sed, grep, tr, awk…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use regex character class subtraction in some way in GNU sed, GNU awk, GNU grep, or anywhere else from bash?

No, not with those tools/regex-implementations.

Most (popular) languages do not support this. Java has a way to do this: `[0-9&&[^25]]` (matching any (ASCII) digit except `'2'` and `'5'`), but I know of no other implementations that support this.

Either use negative look-ahead `(?![25])[0-9]`, as Ignacio already suggested, or do it "the hard way": `[1346-9]`

See:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thank you, your links are very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is with negative lookaheads, but not all regex engines support them.

```
>>> re.match(r'(?![25])[0-9]', '2')
>>> re.match(r'(?![25])[0-9]', '3')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x25108b8>
```